# Error LNK2019 compiling OpenCL Project on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, opencl

I'm getting a lot of erros LNK2019, after I use the nmake command on VS2015 console:

> kmeans.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol clGetPlatformIDs > referenced in function "int __cdecl initialize(int)" (?initialize@@YAHH@Z) kmeans.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol clCreateContextFromType referenced in function "int __cdecl initialize(int)" (?initialize@@YAHH@Z) kmeans.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol clReleaseContext referenced in function "int __cdecl shutdown(void)" (?shutdown@@YAHXZ) kmeans.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol clGetContextInfo referenced in function "int __cdecl initialize(int)" (?initialize@@YAHH@Z) kmeans.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol clCreateCommandQueue referenced in function "int __cdecl initialize(int)" (?initialize@@YAHH@Z) kmeans.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol clReleaseCommandQueue referenced in function "int __cdecl shutdown(void)" (?shutdown@@YAHXZ)

My PC Specs and OS:

- Windows 10 x64
- Core i7 4790k
- GTX 1080.
- NVidia CUDA SDK Installed.

Does anybody know how to fix it, or faced the same problem? Already tried the #pragma with OpenCL Lib but that didnt work.

Already tried to change application type from Windows to console on VS, but that didn't work too.

My CMakeLists.txt is:

> cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )
>
> project( kmeans )
>
> find_package( OpenCL REQUIRED )
>
> include_directories(${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
>
> add_executable( kmeans kmeans.cpp )
>
> target_link_libraries( kmeans ${OPENCL_LIBRARIES} )

Link of the code repository that I'm using:
https://github.com/davidebaltieri31/OpenCL_kMeans

My exact steps:

1. Open VS2015 console.
2. Type "cmake . -G "NMake Makefiles""
3. Type nmake.
4. Then I get the LNK2019 Erros (Full screenshot here: http://puu.sh/uNOWQ/66e8d134a1.png).